# Replace elements in list not matching a sub-string in KDB Q

Tags: kdb

How would I iterate through a list in KDB Q and replace elements which do not match a certain sub-string criteria?

**Logic Example Pseudocode:**

```
list.stream()
    .forEach(x -> {
        if (x matches substring) :
            newList.add(x)
        else :
            newList.add("")
     })
```

**Current List:**

```
S: ("Lint"; "Stack"; "Linode"; "Overflow";"Linux")
```

The sub-string to match is `"Li"` here. As such, strings "Stack" and "Overflow" are replaced by empty Strings as they do not contain the sub-string.

**Resultant List:**

```
S: ("Lint"; ""; "Linode"; "";"Linux")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of ways you could go about it. First iterating over each element using conditional evaluation like below:

```
q){$[x like "Li*";x;" "]}each S
"Lint"
" "
"Linode"
" "
"Linux"
```

Or using an [at apply](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/apply/#apply-at-index-at) like below:

```
q)@[S;where not S like\: "Li*";:;" "]
"Lint"
" "
"Linode"
" "
"Linux"
```

Comment: I would think you want `""` as the default rather than `" "`, otherwise you're mixing types

Comment: No need to use each-left(\:) with like in the second case as like already iterates over the list.

Answer (score 5):

Vector conditional would also work:

```
q)?[S like "Li*";S;count[S]#enlist ""]
"Lint"
""
"Linode"
""
"Linux"
```